# ajax slide show get images from database

Tags: c#

i had sideshow ajax and i want it get images form database 
i used sql server  2000 and i had binary images

this is my code to select images from database

```
public class SlidShow : IHttpHandler
{

    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        using (SqlConnection con = Connection.GetConnection())
        {
            string Sql = "Select image from SlideShowImage Where  Active=1 And Hig_Id=@Hig_Id";
            System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand(Sql, con);
            com.CommandType= System.Data.CommandType.Text;
            com.Parameters.Add(Parameter.NewInt("@Hig_Id", context.Request.QueryString["Hig_ID"].ToString()));

            System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader dr = com.ExecuteReader();
            if (dr.Read() && dr != null)
            {

                Byte[] bytes1 = (Byte[])dr["image"];

                context.Response.BinaryWrite(bytes1);

                dr.Close();
            }
        }
    }
```

---

```
  [System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
    [System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptMethod]

    public static AjaxControlToolkit.Slide[] GetSlides()
    {


        return new AjaxControlToolkit.Slide[] { 
            new AjaxControlToolkit.Slide("images/sharp_highlight_ref_img.jpg", "", ""),
             new AjaxControlToolkit.Slide("images/products_fridg_img.jpg", "", ""),
            new AjaxControlToolkit.Slide("images/sharp_home_highlight_img.jpg", "", "")


        };

    }
}
```

Comment: please edit this and add a question (they're the ones that end with '?'), and you should also show us some code to let us know what you're doing. preferably, point out what you've tried, and what error you're receiving.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do the image loading as a [HttpHandler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/46c5ddfy.aspx), which has to be registred in web.config. You don't really need Ajax for the image loading. Your javascript code has to change the `src` attribute of your `img` tag in order to display a new image.

Here's an example of a http handler which loads a blog from a MS SQL db with a query parameter called `id`.

```
public class IISHandler1 : IHttpHandler
{
    public bool IsReusable
    {
        get { return true; }
    }

    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        int theID;
        if (!int.TryParse(context.Request.QueryString["id"], out theID))
            throw new ArgumentException("No parameter specified");

        context.Response.ContentType = "image/jpeg"; // or gif/png depending on what type of image you have
        Stream strm = DisplayImage(theID);
        byte[] buffer = new byte[2048];
        int byteSeq = strm.Read(buffer, 0, 2048);
        while (byteSeq > 0)
        {
            context.Response.OutputStream.Write(buffer, 0, byteSeq);
            byteSeq = strm.Read(buffer, 0, 2048);
        }
    }

    public Stream DisplayImage(int theID)
    {
        try
        {
            SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString.ToString());
            string sql = "SELECT image FROM Table1 WHERE id = @ID";
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, connection) { CommandType = CommandType.Text })
            {
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", theID);
                connection.Open();
                object theImg = cmd.ExecuteScalar();
                return new MemoryStream((byte[]) theImg);
            }
        }
        catch
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you for your interest but if you assign with java code or all example.

Comment: I'm still unclear what more help you need? The image url's in your slide show must be triggered by what you register for the http handle in web.config. Example. Register a pattern like: /images/slide.ahx?id=. And reference the images like this in your code: new AjaxControlToolkit.Slide("images/slide.ahx?id=1".. etc.