# Convert BLOB to Jpg using C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, database, image

I am currently developing a web application that receives data from an on-site database. The database developers have developed some web-services that I am able to call and send/receive data to and from the the database.

When I want to display an image the method returns the image in BLOB format. My question is: what is the best way to convert BLOB to .jpg or .bmp so I can display the image correctly? If someone could point me in the right direction that would be great!

Cheers,
Tristan

Comment: Is it BLOB like a byte[] array, and you want to serve up the image to a browser?

Comment: Yes, exactly. My experience is pretty limited when it comes to this end of things.

Comment: See this question/answer - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2506536/ajax-slide-show-get-images-from-database/2506618#2506618. It uses a protocol handler to server up images. You can also do it from a .aspx page, but a protocol handler is more clean imo.

Comment: Thanks man. I'm checking out all of my options. Thanks everyone for the help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a generic handler (ashx file) and have it return the byte array.

For example, the url http://www.example.com/GetImage.ashx?imageId=1 could contain code to write the bytes received from the image with id of 1.

You will need to implement the handler code yourself to do the database query, etc. and write the bytes out to the response. You will also need to set the response mime type to jpg, png or whatever format your images are in.

Check out this stackoverflow post for more details: [How to bind a MemoryStream to asp:image control?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46788/how-to-bind-a-memorystream-to-aspimage-control)

Answer (score 0):

There is no one image format associated with BLOB.  It's simply a way of putting raw binary in a database.  You need to figure out which format it actually is ([libmagic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Libmagic) may help), then you can convert if needed.

Answer (score 0):

byte[] array and mimetype are the key words :)